# Работа addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Приветствую.

Кто-то сталкивался с проблемой, что если задаешь имя классу вида: `.10{}` (имя состоит из цифр), `.12s{}` (имя состоит из цифры и алфавитного символа в конце имени), то при попытке добавить класс "такого" вида, результата не будет. Класс вида: `.s12{}` - добавляет.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это не связано с addClass, просто по стандартам CSS классы должны начинаться с [-_a-z]

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все работает (см. пример ниже)? Только селекторы, начинающиеся с цифры в CSS префиксить надо. Ну и вообще это не самая светаля идея.

Здесь много текста про цифры в CSS: 
http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

```js
$("div").addClass("10");
```

```css
.\31 0 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>XXX</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У [CSS есть правила именования](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

Кратко:

- имя должно начинаться с "_", "-" или [a-z]
- и [дискуссия](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors) по этому поводу on stackoverflow